# Set background image when touching button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

On click of a button I am changing the background image. This is only staying for the highlighted state. I want to keep that green/red background image after clicking the button.

How do I do this in my code below? Sorry I am a Newbie...

```
- (void)setCorrectAndWrongAnswerBackgroundImagesForOptions
{
int correctAns = [[currentQuestionDict objectForKey:kQuizAnswer] intValue];
int i;
int count = [_optionsButtonsArray count];
for (i=0; i<count; i++) 
{
    UIButton* optionButton = [_optionsButtonsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString* optionBgImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"optionBg_default%d",(i+1)];
    NSString* optionBgRedImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"optionBg_red%d",(i+1)];
    NSString* optionBgGreenImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"optionBg_green%d",(i+1)];

    if (optionButton.tag == correctAns) 
    {
        [optionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[HAUtilities resourceNameForString:optionBgImageName]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [optionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[HAUtilities resourceNameForString:optionBgGreenImageName]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


    }
    else {
        [optionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[HAUtilities resourceNameForString:optionBgImageName]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [optionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[HAUtilities resourceNameForString:optionBgRedImageName]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in optionButton selector

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [sender setHighlighted:YES];
});
```

That will make optionButton highlighted state to remain until you set it to `NO` again.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the colour on the normal state, at the moment you're changing the highlighted state.

Change your code as follows:

```
- (void)setCorrectAndWrongAnswerBackgroundImagesForOptions
{
int correctAns = [[currentQuestionDict objectForKey:kQuizAnswer] intValue];
int i;
int count = [_optionsButtonsArray count];
for (i=0; i<count; i++) 
{
    UIButton* optionButton = [_optionsButtonsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString* optionBgImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"optionBg_default%d",(i+1)];
    NSString* optionBgRedImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"optionBg_red%d",(i+1)];
    NSString* optionBgGreenImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"optionBg_green%d",(i+1)];

    if (optionButton.tag == correctAns) 
    {
        [optionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[HAUtilities resourceNameForString:optionBgGreenImageName]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else {

        [optionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[HAUtilities resourceNameForString:optionBgRedImageName]] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard when the button is selected, in the right bar their is a drop-down menu with the option 'Highlighted'. Click this and set the attributes you want the button to have when highlighted (selected), such as a different background image.